# VirtualBox import Error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro

I am trying to import exported virtual machine on my using VirtualBox but while importing I am getting the following error:

```
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 1118 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

The complete output of the import command:

```
vboxmanage import arkajit_3_32_devvm.ova 
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /home/siddhesh/arkajit_3_32_devvm.ova...
OK.
Disks:
  vmdisk2   85899345920 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   arkajit_3_32_devvm-disk1.vmdk   -1  -1  

Virtual system 0:
 0: Suggested OS type: "RedHat_64"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
 1: Suggested VM name "3_32_devvm"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --vmname <name>")
 2: Suggested VM group "/"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --group <group>")
 3: Suggested VM settings file name "/home/siddhesh/VirtualBox VMs/3_32_devvm/3_32_devvm.vbox"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --settingsfile <filename>")
 4: Suggested VM base folder "/home/siddhesh/VirtualBox VMs"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --basefolder <path>")
 5: Number of CPUs: 1
    (change with "--vsys 0 --cpus <n>")
 6: Guest memory: 4096 MB
    (change with "--vsys 0 --memory <MB>")
 7: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 7 --ignore")
 8: USB controller
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 8 --ignore")
 9: Network adapter: orig Bridged, config 3, extra slot=0;type=Bridged
10: CD-ROM
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 10 --ignore")
11: IDE controller, type PIIX4
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 11 --ignore")
12: IDE controller, type PIIX4
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 12 --ignore")
13: SATA controller, type AHCI
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 13 --ignore")
14: Hard disk image: source image=arkajit_3_32_devvm-disk1.vmdk, target path=arkajit_3_32_devvm-disk1.vmdk, controller=13;channel=0
    (change target path with "--vsys 0 --unit 14 --disk path";
    disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 14 --ignore")
0%...10%...20%...30%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 1118 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Configurations:

```
OS: manjaro Linux
VirtualBox: 6.1.8 r137981
Guest os iso: 6.1.8
Free Disk Space: 393Gb
```